# Отслеживание состояния checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 5 текстовых полей (`input`) и один `checkbox`. Необходимо сделать проверку если все 5 полей имеют одинаковое значение тогда `checkbox` имеет атрибут `checked` и при вводе в первое поле текст дублируется в 4 и 5 поле, а во второе и 3 идет транслитерация введенного текста. А если `checkbox` `checked` тогда при вводе в первое поле идет транслитерация во второе и все. Если мы сняли галочку а потом опять поставили опять текст должен вводится во все поля. Транслитерация с во второе поле происходит за счет плагина здесь проблем нет.
Вот что у меня есть:

```js
var navigationsPageTitle = $('#navigations-page_title').val(), //Заголовок страницы
  navigationsPrettyUrl = $('#navigations-pretty_url').val(), //Адрес странциы
  navigationsAlias = $('#navigations-alias').val(), //Псевдоним
  navigationsNavigationLabel = $('#navigations-navigation_label').val(), //Название в меню
  navigationsBreadcrumbLabel = $('#navigations-breadcrumb_label').val(), //НАзвание в хлебных крошках
  doubleFields = $('#double-fields'); //Checkbox


if (navigationsPageTitle == navigationsNavigationLabel &&
  navigationsNavigationLabel == navigationsBreadcrumbLabel &&
  navigationsPrettyUrl == navigationsAlias) {
  doubleFields.prop('checked', true);

  if (doubleFields.prop('checked')) {
    $('#navigations-page_title').on('keyup', function() {
      $('#navigations-breadcrumb_label').val($(this).val());
      $('#navigations-navigation_label').val($(this).val());
      $('#navigations-alias').val($('#navigations-pretty_url').val());

    });
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="navigations-page_title" class="input" name="Navigations[page_title]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="double[fields]" id="double-fields">
<input type="text" id="navigations-pretty_url" class="show" name="Navigations[pretty_url]">
<input type="text" id="navigations-alias" name="Navigations[alias]">
<input type="text" id="navigations-navigation_label" name="Navigations[navigation_label]">
<input type="text" id="navigations-breadcrumb_label" name="Navigations[breadcrumb_label]">
```

Код рабочий, но не как не могу реализовать логику

Answer (score 0):

Описал для вас примерное поведение вашей логики с некоторыми уточнениями. Задача решается через 2 слушателя событий. для инпута и чекбокса.

```js
let $input1 = $('input1'),
  $input2 = $('input2'),
  $input3 = $('input3'),
  $input4 = $('input4'),
  $input5 = $('input5'),
  $checkbox = $('checkbox'),
  checkboxChange = false; //флаг для чекбокса

//При вводе в 1 дублируем в 4 и 5
$input1.on('input', event => {
  let value = event.target.value;

  $input4.val(value);
  $input5.val(value);

  //Тут код транслитерации
  let translate = '...';

  $input2.val(translate);
  $input3.val(translate);

  //Непонятно как вы хотите чтобы все 5 полей были равны между собой, если в 2 и 3 транслиртерация текста. Если эти поля автоматически заполняются, можно убрать их из проверки.
  if ($input1.val() == $input4.val() && $input1.val() == $input5.val()) {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$checkbox.on('change'
  event => {
    //Елси чекбокс установили в true и до этого его не меняли
    if ($checkbox.prop('checked') && checkboxChange === false) {
      checkboxChange = true;
      //some logic....
    }
  });
```